# Lookup on ObjectIds in an array of strings in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, lookup, objectid

Suppose I have a collection Book with a field Genres as following:

```
Book: { 
_id: ObjectId('id')
Title: "Book1"
Genres: {"id1","id2"}
}
```

And a second collection Genre:

```
Genre: [{
_id: ObjectId('id1')
Title: "Thriller"
},{
_id: ObjectId('id2')
Title: "Fantasy"
}]
```

When I perform lookup on the two collections to apply some filters on the Title, the result I get is an empty array. How can I parse the strings ids to ObjectId while I'm performing my lookup aggregation?

I'm kinda new to mongodb and can not find enough resources to help me out. Hope someone can help me find the solution in c# .net

Comment: Is there any reason why your design is like this? Wouldn't it make sense for genres to be an array of ObjectId?

Comment: I think you'd need a projection stage before the lookup, then you can map the array of string to array of objectid with a combination of `$map` and `$toObjectId`. Unfortunately, I don't have a computer with me to test this.

Comment: You are showing what I assume is JSON for your data. You are not showing your C# lookup code that isn't working.